# Android device rotation doesn't match the documentation

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, magnetometer

I'm trying to find out the rotation of a device (Samsung Galaxy S5), and I'm following [the method described in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-orient):

```
private float[] rawDeviceRotation;
private float[] rawDeviceAcceleration;
private float[] rawGeomagnetic;

private float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
float[] orientation = new float[3];

// ...

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
        rawDeviceRotation = event.values.clone();
    }
    else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        rawDeviceAcceleration = event.values.clone();
    }
    else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        rawGeomagnetic = event.values.clone();

        if( SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, rawDeviceAcceleration, rawGeomagnetic) ){
            SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientation);

            // orientation[0] ~ -0.62 <-> +0.62
            // orientation[1] ~ -0.31 <-> +0.31
            // orientation[2] ~ -0.62 <-> +0.62
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting *something*, but not the values that the documentation states.

> **Azimuth** (degrees of rotation about the -z axis). This is the angle between the device's current compass direction and magnetic north. If the top edge of the device faces magnetic north, the azimuth is 0 degrees; if the top edge faces south, the azimuth is 180 degrees. Similarly, if the top edge faces east, the azimuth is 90 degrees, and if the top edge faces west, the azimuth is 270 degrees.
>
> **Pitch** (degrees of rotation about the x axis). This is the angle between a plane parallel to the device's screen and a plane parallel to the ground. If you hold the device parallel to the ground with the bottom edge closest to you and tilt the top edge of the device toward the ground, the pitch angle becomes positive. Tilting in the opposite direction— moving the top edge of the device away from the ground—causes the pitch angle to become negative. The range of values is -180 degrees to 180 degrees.
>
> **Roll** (degrees of rotation about the y axis). This is the angle between a plane perpendicular to the device's screen and a plane perpendicular to the ground. If you hold the device parallel to the ground with the bottom edge closest to you and tilt the left edge of the device toward the ground, the roll angle becomes positive. Tilting in the opposite direction—moving the right edge of the device toward the ground— causes the roll angle to become negative. The range of values is -90 degrees to 90 degrees.

First of all, the ranges of values I'm getting don't seem to have much to do with either radians or degrees.

Second, the roll angle (or whatever the value is), becomes *negative* if tilt it to the left as described in the documentation, and vice versa.

Either I'm doing something totally wrong, Samsung is doing something wrong, or the documentation is wrong... any ideas who to blame (and what to do to fix it)?

I tested the phone's sensors using the built in Samsung test screen, reachable by entering `*#0*#` in the dial pad. It's reporting correct tilt angles, passing all self tests, etc. so it seems very unlikely that it is a hardware issue. I'm running Android 4.4.2 on this device.

PS. I tried applying `Math.toDegrees()` on the values - not getting any sane values (no `90°`, `180°` or anything like that).